# loop que Renomeia vários arquivos .txt com o conteúdo do próprio usando uma .bat

Tags: php

Bom dia,
Tenho vários arquivos *.TXT* com nomes aleatórios, e gostaria de renomeá-los.
Porém, gostaria de renomear com uma informação que está na primeira linha do próprio *.txt*.

> Ex. Nome atual do arquivo: TD0303051209344700001AF-0000-1562.txt
>
> E na primeira linha dentro do txt eu tenho: 00000000000001899970462605
>   201804232018042018051220180508982

O novo nome do arquivo dever ser *899970462605* (que está na coluna 15 até a 27).

Agora preciso fazer isso 350 vezes.
pois os arquivos tem esses nomes:

*TD0303051209344700001AF-0000-1564.txt*

*TD0303051209344700001AF-0000-1565.txt*

*TD0303051209344700001AF-0000-1566.txt*

Como criar esse looping??
Obrigado

Comment: Inclua o que você já tentou escrever, indicando exatamente onde está encontrando dificuldades.

Comment: Conforme comentado por  @Leandro Angelo, aqui não é uma empresa de desenvolvimento de código. O mais ético é você mostrar o que você já tentou e postar seu código aqui para saber no que pode ser ajudado.

Comment: Bem-vindo Roberto Munhoz, alguns posts que lhe ajudarão nas próximas perguntas: exemplo minimo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Como não fazer perguntas  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/

Comment: Não deixe de ver como aceitar uma resposta em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score -1):

> Bom, você queria saber como faz, então comentei o Script ...

```
@echo off

REM - Altera a largura e altura da janela   
mode 40,4

REM - Junta em um TXT o nome com a extensão de todos os arquivos de texto do diretório atual  
REM - porém impede que o "nomes.txt" seja jogado também.  
dir /b *.txt | findstr /v "nomes.txt">nomes.txt


REM - Permite o uso de variáveis dentro do comando FOR  
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


REM - Mensagem na tela  
echo.&echo. RENOMEANDO ARQUIVOS ...

REM - Comando for lendo o "nomes.txt"  
REM - Pegando todas as colunas e linhas  
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%A in (nomes.txt) do (

REM - Variável recebendo como valor  
REM - O nome da primeira linha do arquivo "nomes.txt"  
set arquivo=%%A

REM - Variável recebendo o valor da variável arquivo  
REM - que é o nome do primeiro arquivo que será tratado  
REM - E automaticamente passando a ter como valor  
REM - A primeira linha desse arquivo como valor  
set /p line=< !arquivo!

REM - Variável nome recebendo como valor, o valor de !line!  
REM - ignorando as 14 primeiras colunas  
REM - e recebendo as próximas 12 colunas como valor  
set nome=!line:~14,12!

REM - Renomeando o primeiro arquivo com as colunas indicadas  
ren "!arquivo!" "!nome!".txt

REM - Fim do comando FOR  
)

REM - Limpa a tela  
cls

REM - Mensagem na tela de fim do Script  
echo.&echo.    FIM DO SCRIPT ! &pause >nul
```